# Supplementary examinations causing delay in getting a degree

Tags: resume

I enrolled in my degree in 2009, and completed my course hours at University in 2013. I couldn't pass some exams because I was working on my startup. After 2 years, I sat a supplementary exam and got my degree in 2015.

Should I mention the education period in the University from 2009-2013 or 2009-2015?  I was told by one person that if you have completed course hours in 2013, than you can write 2009-2013 on your resume.

What would be the most appropriate way to show this on my CV?

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace -- thanks for your question. I don't know that this has a right/wrong answer, so maybe rephrase your question to include what you are hoping to accomplish/avoid as a result of the education dates?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @mcknz. I am following this resume pattern http://careercup.com/resume and it includes dates of education and jobs taken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to me to be a regional question.  In the US, it is expected that you received your degree at the end of the period noted as being in university.  But, also in the US, any examinations you take are part of your courses, so you cannot delay taking them.

Also in the US, I don't think employers will particularly care when you received your degree, as long as they can verify you received it, and the year may help them to verify when you received it.

Therefore, I suggest either put down your years as 2009-2015, or put down university X 2009-2013, degree received 2015.

Comment: The terminology is normally "_awarded_ degree 2015" :)

Comment: @JaneS: How about I just mention the year of passing university and miss to mention the year of enrollment?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're likely going to need to present your degree along with a statement of results at some point it's important to send a consistent message.

Simply showing when you were awarded the degree will more than suffice for a resume and since you didn't actually receive the degree until 2015 you should state that as the year received. Further timing will come up in an interview if they're interested although I think most workplaces will be more interested in what you know, and that you have a degree behind you rather than in what timeframe you learnt it.